# Parametric Curves

Tags: multivariable-calculus, parametric, plane-curves, arc-length

I'm doing a question like this:

Consider the plane curve $\mathcal{C} = \mathbf{c}(x(t), y(t))$ with the following parametric description:

$$x(t) = \int_0^t\cos\frac{k\tau^2}{2}d\tau\space\space and\space\space y(t) = \int_0^t\sin\frac{k\tau^2}{2}d\tau$$

Where $k \in \mathbb{R}$

Show that $t$ is the arc-length parameter for $\mathcal{C}$, measured from $(0,0)$.

And,

Find the curvature of $\mathcal{C}$.

My question is, can the first part of the question simply be solved by using

$$x'(t) = \cos\frac{k\tau^2}{2}\space\space and\space\space y'(t) = \sin\frac{k\tau^2}{2}$$

and taking the absolute value of these two functions and then integrating that result from 0 to t with respect to t?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The arc length being given by $$L=\int_a^b \sqrt{x'^2+y'^2}\,dt$$ you just need to apply the fundamental theorem of calculus to get the required derivatives (this is what you wrote except that you need to use $t$ and not $\tau$).

Then, remembering that $\sin^2(c)+\cos^2(c)=1$ which will show your result.

Comment: Am I correct in assuming that the values for the limits a and b will be 0 and t, respectively?

Comment: @NathanLowe. If I may suggest : avoid multiple $t$'s when you face integrals with respect to $t$. Say that the limits are $t_1$ and $t_2$ if you want or $0$ and $T$.